# Numerical analysis , using Taylor Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

On interval [$-\pi ,\pi$ ] , show that $1-\frac{{x}^{2}}{2}\le \cos\left(x\right)$ by using Taylor theorem.

I thought that choose ${x}_{0}=0$ and $f(x)=\cos\left(x\right)$. Then,

$f\text{'}(x)=-\sin\left(x\right)$ , $f\text{'}\text{'}(x)=-cos\left(x\right)$ and $f\text{'}\text{'}\text{'}(x)=sin\left(x\right)$ then by Taylor theorem, expansion of function is ,

$\cos(x)=1-\frac{{x}^{2}}{2}+\sin\left(\xi (x)\right)\frac{{x}^{3}}{6}$

But then I stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @MartinR: in this question, the focus is not on Taylor.

Comment: If $x\ne 0$ then $\xi(x)$ is $between  $ $x$ and $0.$ So if $0<| x|< \pi$ then $\sin \xi(x)$ and $x^3$ have the same sign.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1: $x \in [0, \pi]$, then $ \xi(x) \in [0,\pi]$, hence $\sin\left(\xi (x)\right)\frac{{x}^{3}}{6} \ge 0.$ Thus $1-\frac{{x}^{2}}{2}\le \cos\left(x\right)$

Case 2: $ x \in [- \pi,0]$. Then  $ -x \in [0,\pi]$. Case 1 now shows:

$1-\frac{{x}^{2}}{2}= 1-\frac{{(-x)}^{2}}{2} \le \cos(-x) = \cos(x).$

Comment: thanks a lot for help